# Finding $9^{123456789} \pmod{100}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$9^{123456789} \pmod{100}$

I tried to do this in a simpler way:

$$9 \equiv 9 \pmod{100}$$

$$9^1 \equiv 09 \\
9^2 \equiv 81 \\
9^3 \equiv 29 \\
9^4 \equiv 61 \\
9^5 \equiv 49 \\
9^6 \equiv 41 \\
9^7 \equiv 69 \\
9^8 \equiv 21 \\
9^9 \equiv 89 \\
9^{10} \equiv 01$$

I noticed that the odd powers always end in 9 and the even ones in $1$. The leftmost digit follows the sequence $0,2,4,6,8,$... in this order for odd numbers and the other way around for even ones. The sequence has $5$ numbers.

$123456789$ is an odd number. $123456789 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ so the answer should be $69,$ which is the $4$th of the sequence... but it's $89.$ Close enough, but not quite. What did I do wrong and how can I solve this in this way?

Comment: because $123456789\equiv 9\pmod \{10\}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342046/9123456789-pmod100-retrace-calculation-operation

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya thats where I got the question from. I was trying to go about it differently

Comment: $$9^{2a + b} = ({9^a})^2 \cdot 9^b\quad\quad b \in \{0, 1\}$$

Comment: By [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\bmod 100\!:\,\ 9^{\large\color{#c00}{10}}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,9^{\large N}\equiv 9^{\large N\bmod \color{#c00}{10}}\equiv 9^{\large 9}\equiv 89\,$ by your table.

Comment: What's wrong: $\,n\equiv 4\pmod{\!5}\!\iff\! n\equiv 4,9\pmod{\!10},\,$ so $\,n\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\,n\equiv 9\ $ (not $7)\ \pmod{\!10}\ \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry I dont follow.

Comment: My prior comment explains the correct way to do your final paragraph. What precisely don't you follow?  But it is obvious that $N\bmod 10$ is the units digits $9$ so their is no need for that. But you wanted an explanation....

Comment: OP, your approach is an issue of mapping/indexing. You need odd exponents ending in $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ to map to leading digits $0, 2, 4, 6, 8$ and even exponents ending in $0, 2, 4, 6, 8$ to map to leading digits $0, 8, 6, 4, 2$. Taking the exponent mod $5$ won't get you what you need here -- in other words just because you get $4$ mod $5$ that doesn't mean it's the same as the $4$th element of your odd sequence.

Comment: @MarcusAndrews My idea was that if you have a sequence that goes 0,2,4,6,8 (5 numbers) the order shouldn't really matter... in other words, you get a sequence for even exponents and one for odd ones and I am trying to use them separately.

Comment: Taking $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ mod $5$ each gets you $1, 3, 0, 2, 4$ which you could use as indices ($0$-indexed) in the list $[4, 0, 6, 2, 8]$ but you see that the order is no longer $[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]$ as you may want.

Comment: In other words, if you are dead set on using mod $5$: For odd exponent $n$, the result is equal to $[4, 0, 6, 2, 8][n \bmod 5] \cdot 10 + 9$, and for even exponent $n$, the result is equal to $[0, 4, 8, 2, 6][n \bmod 5] \cdot 10 + 1$.

Comment: The odds $\!\bmod 10\, $ are $\equiv 1,3,5,7,\color{#c00}9.\,$ Here $\,\color{#c00}9\equiv 4\pmod{\!5}\,$ is the $\color{#0a0}5$'th elt (with $1$-based indexing) of the odd subsequence in your table. But there's no need to break down $\color{#c00}9$ mod $5$ & $2$ when you can simply look up the value of $\,9^{\large \color{#c00}{9}}\!\pmod{\!100}\,$ in your table (penultimate row) - independent of any *indexing*  scheme!

Comment: @BillDubuque Hold on, why mod 10?

Comment: Because, by my first comment above, we can reduce the exponent $\bmod 10\ \ $

Comment: You missed that You'd have to mod ${123456790\over 2}=61728395$  by 5 to get where it lands in the odd sequence labelling it with $9=2(5)-1$ being 0 instead of 5. then you get  you should be looking at the exponent 9, not 7. It's a tedious way though.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, that's okay, just write that in the post. (:

Answer (score 1):

Given your column of results, \begin{align*}
9^{123456789} &= 9^{12345678 \cdot 10 + 9}  \\
    &= (9^{10})^{12345678}9^9  \\
    &\cong 1^{12345678} \cdot{89} \pmod{100}  \\
    &\cong 89 \pmod{100}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: More conceptually: by  [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\bmod 100\!:\,\ 9^{\large\color{#c00}{10}}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,9^{\large N}\equiv 9^{\large N\bmod \color{#c00}{10}}\equiv 9^{\large 9}\equiv 89\,$ by OP's table.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 9^{10}     \equiv 1 \pmod {25}   $$

Comment: Why mod 25 and not 100?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire If you figure it out mod 25 and mod 4, you can use chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: OP **already knows** $9^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$ so this adds *nothing at all*. Please *read* the question before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Using Binomial Theorem, we get

$$9^{123456789}=(-1+10)^{123456789}\equiv(-1)^{123456789}+123456789\cdot10^1\cdot(-1)^{123456789-1}\equiv-1+90\equiv89 \pmod{100}$$

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question ("What did I do wrong and how can I solve this in *this* way?")